# How to change the "From:" text in WooCoomerce Bookings

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

Im trying to change the text of the display "From" to "Price",

[image: This image]

I tried this filter but the display still the same,.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bookings_booking_cost_string', function( $text ) {
    if ( 'From' == $text ) {
        $text = __( 'Price', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $text;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed ':'.  Try this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_bookings_booking_cost_string',function( $text ) {
        if ( 'From:' == $text ) {
            $text = __( 'Price', 'woocommerce' );
        }

        return $text;
    } );
```

If it doesn't work, try this way: (This will filter text with its translation)

```
add_filter('gettext', 'mw_translate_words_array');
add_filter('ngettext', 'mw_translate_words_array');
function mw_translate_words_array($translated) {
   $words = array( 'From:' => 'Price:'); 
   $translated = str_ireplace(array_keys($words), $words, $translated);
  return $translated;
}
```

Comment: I already tried this one, but still no result,

Comment: I edited the response try the new way plaese

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, It work thank you so much, <3